# Dynamic mean of randomly distributed events

Tags: bayesian, sample-size, mean, measurement-error

The aim is to estimate an error on a stochastic event rate dynamically.

[This Question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2894/dynamic-calculation-of-number-of-samples-required-to-estimate-the-mean) points in the same direction, I am interested in a theoretical extension.

I read out the event counter second-wise, every black $1$ is a counted event (new events over time, see the plot below).

During the measurement I am estimating the event rate, so as more statistics is accumulated, mean event rate (red) should asymptotically become more accurate.

[image: dyn_mean1]

As one can see, the mean value oscillates around true value of 0.5,

[image: dyn_mean2]

even after one order of magnitude more events collected.

**Practical question:** How can one calculate the number of events needed to estimate the mean value to a maximum error ($0.5\pm \sigma$)? - **answered (?) [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2894/dynamic-calculation-of-number-of-samples-required-to-estimate-the-mean/2898#2898)**

**Theoretical question:** Can this oscillation be described analytically? Can you suggest further reading?

The events are radiation counts, so they are uncorrelated, may by Poisson-distribution applied?

**Addendum:**
Idealized first approximation - every 10th event is non-zero:
[image: dyn_mean_reg1]

May be this curve is superimposed with the realer-life example above, is any techniques of partitioning in arbitrary functions applicable here?

Comment: See my comment to the referenced question.  For the theoretical question, read about Brownian motion and random walks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an answer to your first "theoretical" question `Can this oscillation be described analytically? Can you suggest further reading?`

If I understand your question correctly, you are in the situation of [independent identically distributed random variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables) with finite variance $\sigma^2$. In this case the [law of the iterated logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm) applies which tells you that you should expect the difference between estimated mean and mean to oscillate between $-\sigma$ and $+\sigma$, *if you normalize it by dividing by* $\sqrt{2n\log{\log{n}}}$.

The linked wikipedia pages are good for a first reading. [Wolfram](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheLawOfTheIteratedLogarithmInProbabilityTheory/) offers a demo (which didn't work in my browser).

Answer (score 1):

If you are estimating an unknown probability $p$, then, assuming i.i.d. nature of your events, the count $X$ is Binomial, with variance $np(1-p)$, where $n$ is the total number of events. The estimated proportion is $\hat p = X/n$ with variance $p(1-p)/n\le 0.5 \cdot 0.5 / n = 0.25/n$ for any $p$. For a given margin of error $m$, you can say that, approximately, $\mbox{Prob}[ |\hat p-p|>m ] \le \mbox{Prob}[ |Z|>m/(0.5/\sqrt{n}) ]$ where $Z$ is the standard normal variate. (You can do exact calculations with `pbinom` if you really need to.) For a 5% tail probability, we have $m/(0.5/\sqrt{n})=1.96$; $n=(1.96/2m)^2$, so for 3% accuracy, we have $n=(1.96/(2\cdot0.03))^2 = 1067$. This gives you an answer to an unrelated question: Why are polls always conducted for the sample size of 1000 or so? (Answer: to get this 3% accuracy with 95% confidence.)

You can of course approach this from the point of view of Bayesian updating with say a Jeffrey's prior $\propto [p(1-p)]^{-1/2}$ (i.e., $B(\frac12, \frac12)$ distribution), and getting your data in until variance of the posterior (also a Beta distribution) is small enough. The above derivation, essentially, assumes a flat prior, $B(1,1)$.