# Convergence of covariance matrix

Tags: variance, covariance, convergence, covariance-matrix

I was looking for a simple way to find the number of samples $n$ needed to get a decent approximation to the covariance matrix $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$. Given a random sample $\{ \mathbf{X}_1,\mathbf{X}_2, \dots ,\mathbf{X}_n\}$, the sample covariance matrix is

$$ \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{n} = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum^{n}_{k=1}  \left( \boldsymbol{\mathbf{X}}_k -  \overline{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{X}}}  \right)\left(\boldsymbol{\mathbf{X}}_k -  \overline{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{X}}} \right)^T  $$

I want to plot the number of samples $n$ (on the x-axis) vs some scalar value computed from the estimate $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{n}$ (on the y-axis). What quantity can I compute in a simple way to plot such a convergence graph?. What about the matrix norm $\left \| \cdot \right \|_2$, i.e. the maximum singular value of $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{n}$?.

Comment: The near-duplicate at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59478/when-data-has-a-gaussian-distribution-how-many-samples-will-characterise-it/61068#61068 focuses on the multivariate Normal distribution, but its answers can be generalized.

Comment: Did you look at Wishart distribution already?