# How to estimate the variance of correlated observations?

Tags: correlation, variance, estimation, intraclass-correlation

Assume we have n observations $x_i$ (i from 1 to n), each from the a normal distribution with mean 0 and some variance component: $X_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$. The random variables $X_i$s have some (let's assume known) correlation structure. I.e.: $Corr(X_i, X_j) = \rho_{ij}$.

How should we estimate $\sigma^2$?

How would the correlated structure impact an estimator such as $\hat \sigma^2 = \frac{\sum(x_i^2)}{n}$? Could we devise a better estimator (given the correlation structure is known)?

Comment: Seems you have much more unknown parameters than observations. Unless $\rho_{ij}$ has some pattern, it would be very hard to treat this problem under the canonical statistical inference framework.

Comment: @Zhanxiong That remark is reminiscent of a common misunderstanding discussed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/61068/919.

Comment: @whuber I didn't read the question carefully, thinking $\rho_{ij}$s are unknown.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $R = (\rho_{ij})$ be the correlation matrix so that the covariance matrix is  $\Sigma = \sigma^2 R.$  Consider $\mathbf x = (x_1,\ldots, x_n)^\prime$ to be a *single* observation of the [$n$-variate Normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) with zero mean and $\Sigma$ covariance.  Because the log likelihood of $N\ge 1$ independent such observations is, up to an additive constant (depending only on $N,$ $n,$ and $R$) given by

$$\Lambda(\sigma) = \sum_{i=1}^N (-n \log \sigma) - \frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \sum_{i = 1}^N\mathbf{x}_i^\prime\, R^{-1}\,\mathbf{x}_i,$$

it has critical points where $\sigma\to 0,$ $\sigma\to\infty,$ and at any solutions of

$$0 = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm{d}\sigma}\Lambda(\sigma) = -\frac{nN}{\sigma} + \frac{1}{\sigma^3} \sum_{i = 1}^N\mathbf{x}_i^\prime\, R^{-1}\,\mathbf{x}_i.$$

Unless the form $ \sum_{i = 1}^N\mathbf{x}_i^\prime\, R^{-1}\,\mathbf{x}_i$ is zero, there is a unique global maximum at

> $$\hat\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{nN} \sum_{i = 1}^N \mathbf{x}_i^\prime\, R^{-1}\,\mathbf{x}_i.$$

This is the Maximum Likelihood estimate.  *It exists even when $N=1$* (which is the situation posited in the question).

**Intuitively, this will be superior to any estimate that ignores the correlations assumed in $R.$**  To check, we could compute the Fisher Information matrix for this estimate -- but I will leave that to you, in part because the result shouldn't be convincing for small values of $N$ (where the maximum likelihood asymptotic results might not apply).

**To illustrate what actually happens,** here are one thousand estimates of $\sigma^2$ from experiments with $n=4$ and $N=1.$  The value of $\sigma$ was set to $1$ throughout.  In these experiments, the correlation was always

$$R = \pmatrix{1 &0.3055569  &0.5513377  &0.5100989\\
0.3055569 &1  &0.1240151  &0.09634469\\
0.5513377 &0.12401511  &1 &-0.4209064\\
0.5100989 &0.09634469 &-0.4209064  &1}$$

(as generated randomly at the outset).  In the figure the leftmost panel is a histogram of the foregoing Maximum Likelihood estimates; the middle panel is a histogram of estimates using the usual (unbiased) variance estimator; and the right panel is a QQ plot of the two sets of estimates.  The slanted line is the line of equality.  You can see **the usual variance estimator tends to yield more extreme values.**  It is also biased (due to ignoring the correlation): the mean of the MLEs is 0.986 -- surprisingly close to the true value of $\sigma^2 =1^2 =1$ while the mean of the usual estimates is only 0.791.  (I write "surprisingly" because it is well-known the usual maximum likelihood estimator of $\sigma^2,$ where no correlation is involved, has a bias of order $1/(nN),$ which is pretty large in this case.)

[image: Figure]

You may experiment with the `R` code that produced these figures by modifying the values of `n`, `sigma`, `N`, `n.sim`, `Rho`, and the random number seed `17`.

```R
f <- function(x, Rho) { # The MLE of sigma^2 given data `x` and correlation `Rho`
  S <- solve(Rho)
  sum(apply(x, 1, function(x) x %*% S %*% x)) / length(c(x))
}
n <- 4
sigma <- 1
N <- 1
n.sim <- 1e3
set.seed(17)
#
# Generate a random correlation matrix.  Larger values of `d` yield more
# spherical matrices in general.
#
d <- 1
Rho <- cor(matrix(rnorm(n*(n+d)), ncol=n))
(ev <- eigen(Rho, only.values=TRUE)$values) 
#
# Run the experiments.
#
library(MASS)
sim <- replicate(n.sim, {
  x <- matrix(mvrnorm(N, rep(0,n), sigma^2 * Rho), N)
  c(f(x, Rho),  var(c(x)))
})
(rowMeans(sim))
#
# Plot the results.
#
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
hist(sim[1,], col=gray(.93), xlab="Estimate", 
     main=expression(paste("Histogram of Estimates of ", sigma^2)))
abline(v = sigma^2, col="Red", lwd=2)

hist(sim[2,],col=gray(.93), xlab="Estimate",
     main=expression(paste("Histogram of Independent Estimates of ", sigma^2)))
abline(v = sigma^2, col="Red", lwd=2)

y1 <- sort(sim[1,])
y2 <- sort(sim[2,])
plot(y1, y2,asp=1, xlab="Correlation-based estimate", ylab="Independent estimate")
abline(0:1, col="Red", lwd=2)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Comment: Fantastic answer - THANKS @whuber!

Answer (score 4):

You can apply GLS equations, e.g. top of p.5 in these lectures:  http://halweb.uc3m.es/esp/Personal/personas/durban/esp/web/notes/gls.pdf

The equation for MSE is $\sigma^2=1/n \sum_{ij} x_i r^{-1}_{ij} x_j$ if you set X to zero and correspond your r to their V

This equation doesn’t work for extreme cases such as correlation 1 between all variables. This case your usual equation will still produce a number

Comment: I think you might have rushed into this answer: my analysis shows that correlation plays an important role.

Comment: @whuber , yep, jumped the shark too early