# How to compare means among groups with a single value?

Tags: anova, analysis-of-means

My aim is to compare means among different groups, but I only have one single value (mean) for each group. I also have the total number of individuals per group. I don't have data for all individuals inside the group as I am comparing results from different papers, so the mean per group is all I have. In some cases I also have SD and the range.

My data looks like:
Group A: n=20, mean= 6.58
Group B: n=2, mean=7.4
Group C: n=15, mean=3.2

---

I would like to compare groups among them but I cannot use ANOVA as it needs the variance within a group. I don't know if there is any other tool to do that.

Comment: If you don't have the variance in each group then you cannot compare the groups statistically. All you can do is make a comment along the lines of... the mean in group A is less/greater than the mean in group B.

Comment: @Mihael It may be surprising that your assertions are not correct: it is possible to construct a confidence interval for the difference between two means, assuming the sampling distribution of the difference is Normal, knowing *only* the difference!  This indicates that meaningful testing of these means is possible even without knowing the variances.

Comment: @whuber a Normal distribution is defined by both mean and variance. I fail to see how a Normal distribution can be useful here when the variance is unknown, without making assumptions. If you could write it out in an answer, I'd be interested to see it.

Comment: @Mihael Please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/1836/919.

Answer (score 5):

The null hypothesis of ANOVA is that the within-group variances are equal and all group means are equal.  **Under this hypothesis, your data provide enough information for testing,** provided you can justify assuming the sampling distributions of the group means are close to Normal.

Here's a brief analysis.  To establish notation, let there be $d\ge 2$ groups of sizes $n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_d$ comprising $N=n_1+\cdots + n_d$ independent observations.  Let the common variance be $\sigma^2$ and the common mean be $\mu.$  If $\mathcal{L}$ is the likelihood, write $\Lambda = -2\log(\mathcal L),$ which is minimized when the likelihood is maximized.

These assumptions imply the group means $x_i$ have Normal$(\mu, \sigma^2/n_i)$ distributions.  Therefore

$$\Lambda = \sum_{i=1}^d \log\left(\frac{\sigma^2}{n_i}\right) + \frac{(x_i-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2/n_i}.$$

Critical values of the gradient of $\Lambda$ produce the familiar estimates

$$\hat \mu = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^d n_i x_i$$

and

$$\hat\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{d}\sum_{i=1}^d n_i(x_i-\hat\mu)^2.$$

At this point it is natural to re-express the data in terms of Z scores as

$$z_i = \frac{x_i - \hat\mu}{\sqrt{\hat\sigma^2 / n_i}}$$

because each of these is approximately standard Normal and they are approximately independent.  Consequently, **you could inspect this set of Z scores for deviations from a standard Normal distribution.**  You might use a Normal-theory outlier test, for instance; or you could construct a statistic such as the Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic or Anderson-Darling statistic.  For formal testing, bootstrapping the distribution of this statistic from the estimates will work (and helps us avoid extensive further analysis!).

---

**As an example,** the estimates for the data $X=(6.58, 7.4, 3.2)$ with group sizes $n=(20, 2, 15)$ are

$$(\hat \mu, \hat\sigma^2) = (5.25, 35.89)$$

with corresponding Z scores

$$z = (0.99, 0.51, -1.33).$$

These aren't unusual, so we haven't found significant evidence of a difference in group means.  Indeed, it's scarcely possible to do so with just three groups--one of the means would have to be far from the other two.

**Suppose, though, that you have more data from more studies and therefore you have means of more than three groups.**  Then this approach could yield significant results.  As an example, consider ten groups with means $x=(1,2,\ldots, 9, 30).$  That last value of $30$ is extreme.  The estimated parameters are now $\hat\mu=7.5$ and $\hat\sigma^2=124.5$ with Z scores

$$z = (-0.82, -0.70, \ldots, 0.06, 0.19, 2.85).$$

That last one ($2.85$) is a little unusual and indeed, the parametric boostrap of the KS statistic gives a p-value of $0.011,$ indicating a significant difference.

The following `R` code gives an implementation.  The p-value for the data in the question is $0.605.$

```r
#
# Data.
#
x <- c(6.58, 7.4, 3.2)
n <- c(20, 2, 15)

# x <- c(1:9, 30)
# n <- rep(2, length(x))
#
# Parameter estimates.
#
theta.hat <- function(x, n) {
  N <- sum(n)
  m <- sum(n*x) / N
  s2 <- mean(n*(x-m)^2)
  c(x.hat=m, s2.hat=s2)
}
(theta <- theta.hat(x, n))
#
# Bootstrap statistic.
#
KS.stat <- function(x, theta, n) {
  max(abs((1:length(x))/(length(x)+1) - sort(pnorm(x, theta["x.hat"], 
      sqrt(theta["s2.hat"]/n)))))
}
stat <- KS.stat(x, theta, n)
#
# Display Z scores.
#
print(signif(x - theta["x.hat"]) / sqrt(theta["s2.hat"] / n), 2)
#
# Bootstrap the statistic.
#
sim <- replicate(1e4, {
  y <- rnorm(length(n), theta["x.hat"], sqrt(theta["s2.hat"]/n))
  p <- theta.hat(y, n)
  KS.stat(y, p, n)
})
print(c(`p-value`=mean(c(stat, sim) >= stat)))
```