# How should I calculate sample size when Cohen's $d$ effect size is $> 5.6$?

Tags: sample-size, effect-size, cohens-d

I am working in R. I am doing some simulations of sample sizes by drawing random samples from two normal distributions.

I am calculating Cohen's $d$ effect size with:

```
library(esc)

esc_mean_sd(grp1m = ..., grp1sd = ..., grp1n = ..., # mean, sd, n of group CONTROL
            grp2m = ..., grp2sd = ..., grp2n = ..., # mean, sd, n of group TEST
            es.type = "d")
```

Note: from package documentation https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/esc/esc.pdf: $d$ is *standardized mean difference effect size $d$*. From the function's source code: `(grp1m - grp2m)/sd_pooled`.

Then I am calculating sample size with:

```
library(pwr)

pwr.t.test(n=NULL, d=..., sig.level=0.05, power=0.8)
```

It happens that I get the following error:

```
Error in uniroot(function(n) eval(p.body) - power, c(2 + 1e-10, 1e+09)) :    f() values at end points not of opposite sign
```

By trial and error, I found it throws the error when $d > 5.65348...$ Anything below is fine. I also noticed sample size at this effect size (and `sig.level=0.05`, `power=0.8`) is exactly $2$.

My current solution is to artificially bring down to $5.6$ any effect size higher than that, and report $2$ as sample size. Is $2$ the theoretical smallest sample size anyway? Is this an accurate fix?

**Reproducible example**

```
library(esc)
library(pwr)
```

**Case1:** $d=2$: does not throw an error

```
ESC <- esc_mean_sd(grp1m = 3, grp1sd = 1, grp1n = 20,
                   grp2m = 1, grp2sd = 1, grp2n = 20,
                   es.type = "d")

pwr.t.test(n=NULL, d=ESC$es, sig.level=0.05, power=0.8)
```

**Case2:** $d=6$: throws an error

```
ESC <- esc_mean_sd(grp1m = 7, grp1sd = 1, grp1n = 20,
                   grp2m = 1, grp2sd = 1, grp2n = 20,
                   es.type = "d")

pwr.t.test(n=NULL, d=ESC$es, sig.level=0.05, power=0.8)
```

Comment: Because there are great many different forms of Cohen's *d,* it is essential that you explain exactly *which* one this software is computing.  In general there are mathematical bounds and they depend on the formula and the data counts.

Comment: I see. "*standardized mean difference effect size d*" from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/esc/esc.pdf. From source code of the function: `(grp1m - grp2m)/sd_pooled`.

Comment: If readers must read source code in order to understand your question, it is unlikely you will get any answers.  Please make the essential information plain within your post.

Comment: Sure. My question could be better formulated anyway. I am not directly asking about the mathematics behind the effect size, more how I should go about calculating sample sizes when $d > 5.6$.

Comment: That's a very different question! In any conceivable situation (except, perhaps, for a finite population) there will be a sample size associated with any effect size. Indeed, the larger the effect size, the smaller the sample that will be needed to detect it.

Comment: That makes sense. Maybe I should think about the problem from the other end, is $2$ the theoretical minimum sample size?

Comment: That's an interesting question.  Its answer depends on how you plan to test the data.  (That is, in part, why there are so many different formulas for Cohen's *d*.)  For instance, in some cases a sample size of $1$ will work: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/1836/919.